# How to determine whether a dvd is re-writable or not?

Tags: dvd

Is there any command or a tool that can tell me if I can rewrite a dvd ??? Because sometimes companies fool you and write on their dvds RW when they are not.

Comment: If you run a DVD burning program, such as k3b, the program will tell you if the DVD is writable or not. There are many reasons a DVD is not writable and I have not seen a company trying to fool you in this way. In my experience I find the slightly more expensive disks are more reliable then the slightly less expensive disks.

Comment: By "companies" do you mean a guy in the alley selling discs out of his trench coat?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Brasero or Xfburn to check all your CD/DVD discs for the rewritable feature. Use each application's menu to list your disc capabilities the same way you do in Windows with Ahead Nero.

There are plenty of other software packages that you can use for CD/DVD burning, and you can test them if unsatisfied with either Brasero or Xfburn. Use Software Center or Synaptic to look for all of them, and install whatever you think it meets your particular requirements.